# Regular expression match with public key

Tags: regex

Hi this is my example `0xc1e5017fbc68aa3e56aa580708de9aa123d62d18`

This is my reg ex `^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,40}`. What I'm doing is `0x` which is compulsory after that we can enter upto 40 alpha numeric digits. But not special characters. What should I do here so it will match correctly?

Comment: Your regex works on your example: https://regex101.com/r/cptOH1/1. What is the issue?

Comment: It is not working in javascript.

Comment: Can you share the Javascript where it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to assert where the string ends, or else you will match up until a special character is found, and get undesired matches.

So with your current regex and test string `0xc1!`, `0xc1` would be matched, even though it is an invalid match.

How about using: [`^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{1,40}$`](https://regex101.com/r/MNCTyf/2)

Comment: that . is not a part of regex.